# Edit Product Archive design for Woo theme

Tags: theme-development, woocommerce-offtopic, child-theme

[image: Design that should be replaced]

Hello,
I am very inexperienced in code and WooCommerce themes. I didn't even get a working child theme out of my Upstart parent theme.
It would be nice if someone could give me some help because I could not manage to solve it.

I have an online shop with a theme that I like really much except of how the product archives look like. I want to change the product archive (is it called loops?) to the standard one.

Does someone know how to do it? 
I have already tried copying a template to /themes/upstart/woocommerce/archive-product.php (I have created the WooCommerce folder in the parent theme) but it won't change anything.

Thank you very much for any effort,

Julian.

Comment: Hi Julian - welcome to WPSE. This is probably something that you need to seek out with your theme developer for support.

Comment: You need to start by creating a child theme, there are a million resources online to help with that, do not edit the theme directly.  Once the child theme is setup you can start to experiment with making edits to your archive template.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have found the fault with the child theme and got the child theme working now. I will try to do the steps again.